# Why this ajax is throwing me a 400 error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i really don't get why it's throwing a 400 error. I did try many different ways but it's always throwing me the same error. I'm using the request through admin-ajax.php
JQUERY:

```
function hyper_faq_ajax(){
  if(is_page(1404)){
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#faq-search").on("keydown", function(){
        var text = jQuery("#faq-search").val();
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>';
        var data = {
            'action': 'frontend_action_testing',
            'name_var': text
        };
        
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
    })
})
</script>
<?php
}
}
add_action("wp_footer", "hyper_faq_ajax");

function frontend_action_testing(){
  echo json_encode($_POST);
  wp_die;
}

add_action("wp_ajax_frontend_action_testing", "frontend_action_testing");
add_action("wp_ajax_no_priv_frontend_action_testing", "frontend_action_testing");
```

[image]

Comment: check the error message in developer bar

Comment: [The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)

Comment: I fixed `wp_die();` but I'm already getting status 200 and the reply I expect without that when I paste your code as-is: `{"action":"frontend_action_testing","name_var":"ffd"}0` It doesn't log it though, because I guess officially the reply fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo.
and the ajax hook for non logged in users is `wp_ajax_nopriv` and not `wp_ajax_no_priv`.
wp_die is a function. So you have to do this `wp_die()`
And to return data you have to use  `wp_send_json();`

here is a working code

```
function frontend_action_testing(){
  wp_send_json($_POST);
}

add_action("wp_ajax_frontend_action_testing", "frontend_action_testing");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_frontend_action_testing", "frontend_action_testing");
```

here is a pic

[image]